# Which one refers to NN model performance? Train metrics, Val metrics or Test metrics

Tags: machine-learning

I have dataset which is split into train:val:test=80:10:10. I have carefully separated the data such that there is no overlap between them but each set is representative of the overall population. I understand that, train is used to fit the model, validation is used to tune the hyperparameters and test data provides unbiased performance of the model as it was not used during training and was unseen.

Once the model is trained, I have model performance on each dataset, now my question is, which one do people refer to in papers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People are free to report whatever they want. They *should* report performance on test data, which is the most informative piece of information, but not everyone does this. And of course they should indicate clearly what they are reporting.

If you read a paper that does not even clarify which data they calculated performance on, that would - to me at least - be a big red flag, and it would make me doubt the competence and detail orientation of the rest of the paper.